# How to find the distance from this point to a straight line?

Tags: distance

```
Clear["Global`*"]
reg = ImplicitRegion[ x + k y == 0, {x, y}]
pt = {-((a^2 k)/Sqrt[b^2 + a^2 k^2]), b^2/Sqrt[b^2 + a^2 k^2]}
RegionDistance[reg, pt]
```

Why is it impossible to find the distance from this point to the straight line?

The known condition is: a > b > 0, and the point is in the first quadrant.  k<0

the right answer is:

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"] 
reg = ImplicitRegion[a x + b y + c == 0, {x, y}] 
pt = {x0, y0}
RegionDistance[reg, pt]
```

Why can't the distance formula from a point to a straight line be derived using code?

Comment: I wouldn't expect RegionDistance to work with undefined terms (e.g. a, b, k).

Comment: Is there any other way to calculate?

Comment: @lericr But it does: `RegionDistance[ImplicitRegion[x + k y == 0, {x, y}], {p1, p2}]`

Comment: You seem to ignore the error message....Why is that?

Comment: “Why is it impossible to find the distance from this point to the straight line?” No, it's possible, if you think a bit more.

Comment: @xzczd Which part needs to be modified?

Comment: The answer is already there, think carefully.

Comment: `Simplify[
 RegionDistance[reg, {p1, p2}] /. Thread[{p1, p2} -> pt], {a > b > 0, 
  k < 0}]`

Comment: @cvgmt ```Clear["Global`*"]
reg = ImplicitRegion[a x + b y + c == 0, {x, y}]
pt = {x0, y0}
RegionDistance[reg, pt]```Why can't the distance formula from a point to a straight line be derived using code?